# Why is SSMS showing red squigglies(sp?) even though the table exists?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, ssms, intellisense

I'm creating a new table and in the process creating two foreign keys. The tables with the primary keys referenced exist but Intellisense is giving the error message: "Foreign key. . .references invalid table 'ROLES'."

Why does SQL Server Management Studio not recognize these tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, the tables are not recognized because the IntelliSense local cache is not up to date.

While you are in the Query Editor window you can press CTRL + SHIFT + R to refresh the cache. This should update IntelliSense's cache and the red squiggles should disappear.

Please see this [link](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2014/02/21/ssms-and-the-intellisense-red-squiggle-mess/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Its a normal behavior as the IntelliSense does not recognize the objects that are not cached.

I use the Refresh cache option in Edit menu each time I see this.

Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache